# How to create new Questionnaire-target pair of record from a single DF?

Tags: datafeed, archer, rsa-archer-grc

My requirement is to create a new Questionnaire-target pair of record for if it already doesnot exists against newly completed Privacy assessment(Q1).

How can we create a A2A datafeed which will generate 1 target application record and 1 Questionnaire record.
I guess may be using the Key mapping (if no match found then create a new record in cross ref also).

but I need to know the details around it.
Input: report from a questionnaire say Q1. (Q1 has target T1)
Output: record in Questionnaire Q2 and its Target application say T2

1. what should be the target of DF?
2. what field must to include in report?
3. Any new field field I need to create?
4. what field in source to map with Target application cross reference?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange question. Only you yourself can answer it since you have the requirements. High level answers:

1. what should be the target of DF?
   Application, since you may need to create a record there first.
2. what field must to include in report?
   You need to include the field you plan to use as a key field in the app.

3.Any new field field I need to create?
No, unless you have a requirement to create one.

4. what field in source to map with Target application cross reference?
   The field you plan to use as a key.

Good luck!